# How to have different font styles when using in php with imagettftext()

Tags: php, html

I am making a meme generator, using the Impact font, and I want to be able to use the version with the black outline and white inside. However, I can't find the font like that by default, how do I style my font so that it looks how I want it to?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Second2None I would try just uploading a font file that looks how I want it, but like I said, I can't find one online. I haven't really tried anything else because I can't seem to find anything in the PHP docs that might do what I need.